# jQuery fadeOut without display none?

Tags: jquery

Is there an alternative to fadeOut() that doesn't use display:none for the style?  I'd like to just use visibility hidden to avoid any sort of shifting in the page layout?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on the `opacity` directly:

```
$(".selector").animate({ opacity: 0 })
```

This way the element still occupies space like you want, it just has a `0` opacity, so it's *effectively* the same as it being `visibility: hidden` when it finishes.

Comment: The user can still click on the element (*e.g.* a link) though, in which case you might want to set `visibility: hidden;` in the completion callback function or something like that.

Comment: I want to hide the element without setting the display to none. Additinaly I dont want the element to keep the space, it looks ugly if there is nothing on the page but the space is still reserved...

Comment: @ObaidMaroof that's precisely the behavior display:none is for... If you're talking about the instant hide you don't want, then you're after .fadeOut() which does display:none *after* a fade.

Answer (score 74):

Yes, there's an alternative. [It's called `.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/), where you set the target opacity, which in your case will be `0`.

```
$('element').fadeTo( 1000, 0 ); // fade to "0" with a 1000ms duration
```

This will not alter the `display` property at the end.

Comment: This does not add display:none when fading to 0, but if you fade to a value above 0 then it forces a display:block (at least when you have display:none). So it does in fact alter the display property under certain circumstances. I had to use animate() to avoid this.

Comment: But what if I want to hide the element so that it doesn't occupy the space in the document (like display none). And all this without setting the display to none.

Comment: This worked great, just had to add both fading to show and fading to hide.    $('#msgInfo').fadeTo(0, 500);
$('#msgInfo').fadeTo(2000, 0);

Answer (score 3):

Custom animation is an alternative
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 5000, 'linear', callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to capture the display mode, then .fadeOut, and in the complete, do your preferred method of hiding, and set the display back to what it was:

```
var $element = $('#selector');

var display = $element.css('display');
$element.fadeOut(500, function() {
   $element.css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
   $element.css('display', display);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I you want to **fadeOut**, then change the content and then **fadeIn** again:

```
$("#layer").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, 'linear', function(){

    //Do here any changes to the content (text, colors, etc.)
    $("#layer").css('background-color','red'); //For example

    $("#layer").animate({opacity: 1}); //FadeIn again

});
```

Comment: Thank you !! this realy help me +1

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
fadeTo(500, 0)   // fade out over half a second
fadeTo(0, 0)     // instantly hide
```

is (oddly) not compatible with

```
fadeIn()
```

(when you want to show it again). So if you are using

`fadeTo(500, 0)`

in order to to hide something without the css `display: none` then you must use

`fadeTo(500, 1)`

to fade it back in or it will still have `opacity: 0` left over in the css and will remain invisible.