# Fade in image when user reaches div#ID + fade out after n more pixels again

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am currently working on a one-page layout for a website. Each section of the page has a corresponding 'topic' logo which I would like to have jQuery fade it in when the user reaches the position. When moving further a certain amount of pixels (like 100px up or down) the image should fade out again. Is there an easy way to do this? The height of each div isn't fixed (CMS behind it), so I couldn't just go with a fixed px amount from the top or something. Of course, if you move further down/up to any of the other divs the images should fade in as in the first place.

Here's my example code

```
<div role="main">
    <div id="first"><img … />content…</div>
    <div id="second"><img … />content…</div>
    <div id="third"><img … />content…</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here's a quick demo of what you are looking for:

- http://jsfiddle.net/G979Q/

No images there, just colored divs, but if that's what you want, you should be able to extend rather easily. Depending on other restrictions of how elements are placed by CMS, you might run into problems, but still the general idea should be applicable.

Edit: just to make sure the comments are captured in the answer, for scrolling-based instead of mouse-based fades, here's a quick demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/3/

Credits:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/calculate-distance-between-mouse-and-element/
- [jQuery fadeOut without display none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549389/jquery-fadeout-without-display-none)
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey icyrock,
thanks for the fast reply. I however might not have been too clear about what I want. 
It's less about mouse but page position - when the user scrolls down to an element with a certain ID, its content or the element should fade in. As soon as he scrolls up/down like 100px the element should fade out again. Something like that. Your example (thank you so much anyway :)) is rather dealing with mouse positioning.

Comment: Not wanting to bother anyone, but anyone here having an idea? I saw parts of what I would need around here, but couldn't connect / don't know if it is possible... Thanks ;).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is what you had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/?

Comment: Hi icyrock, yeah, that's what I meant. Only having two problems:

Comment: 1. Is it by design that the divs do not fade it, the show up immediately. 2. For the container (#main) I cannot specify a specific height (since there is a CMS behind and it should be flexible). Without the height your script doesn't seem to calculate right and leaves the opacity at 0. Can you help me further? Thank you so much so far, getting real close ;).

Comment: Typo for the fade-in - try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/3/. For the other thing, you would have to take a look at how your CMS is designed and modify the examples I provided to suit your needs.

Comment: Hey icyrock, thank you again, working flawlessly in your example with overflow:scroll and a fixed height for the container #main. I however run into problems when using it in my context. What of the CSS is really needed to work for the script? I cannot seem to get it to display in my own example, seems to be connected to overflow:scroll which isn't ideal for my example. The page structure is rather complex to outline it here, but I think it has something to do with the fixed height and overflow:scroll in your example. Can you help further :)?

Comment: I told you I cannot guess what your CMS looks like or its specifics - what did you try to make this work? This does not depend on `overflow: scroll` or `heigth: 400px` - this is just so I make it easier to work with. Here's a version without that: http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/17/.

Comment: Hey there, of course, you cannot guess, the former version just wasn't functional anymore when I stripped down the fixed height parameters. This one is working fine almost without it, except that it needs at least ONE fixed height it seems (on the empty-space things): http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/18/ . If I leave the height completely to the content, the coloured divs don't appear. Same thing on my real-world example. Sine you cannot guess, of course, I'd like to thank you for your help so far, will try to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Not really - here's a version with some text in it and without any width/height: http://jsfiddle.net/CPrcP/19/. The only thing you need is a clearing div at the end (which I suppose you can somehow put to your CMS page), i.e. `<div id="clear"></div>` element. There must be something with your CMS - try things around, be prepared to debug and you should find your solution as long as you get the main idea.

Comment: Yeah, it must be something with the CSS/HTML construct. I can clearly see that no height/width is needed, didn't know about the clear, but had that at the end of my document anyway (using a grid system). Since the layout is a bit more complex (one-page layout) it may be some wrapping div or alike that's producing the pain here, since I see the elements fade out on load, but not fade in again after that. This is real tricky, thanks for helping out so much :D.

Comment: Icyrock!! It was a real stupid mistake. Your last version is pretty fine. I am using it with Wordpress, and other scripts work fine, except that I need to use 'jQuery' instead of the classic '$' for the scroll function. Finally working without any extra height, width, float, whatsoever. You got me 100% happy! Only one thing - the fading out distance (when scrolling down further) is depending on the height of the browser window, not the distance to the element itself, so it stays visible quite long - or did I get something wrong again?

Comment: That's correct, depends on the document height. You can play with it to get different effects. Glad you got the solution you wanted!