# How to stop blinking when text is hovered?

Tags: jquery, css

When you hover the link, it just starts blinking. How can I get it to not blink ? I've tried adding a stop propagation.

I want the text to change but I don't want that blinking effect to happen. I just want it to change at once.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/94f84ngg/)

```js
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function() {
  return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').stop().fadeIn();
    });
  },

  function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function() {
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().fadeIn();
    });
  });
```

```css
.footer_5 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 420px;
}
#hello {
  font-family: 'KeplerStd-MediumDisp';
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer_5">
  <p id="hello"><span class="first">Please say hello.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you don't want to change link text on hover?

Comment: @ketan Sorry I was unclear. I want the text to change but I don't want that blinking effect to happen. I just want it to change at once.

Comment: You really should be doing this with css, not jquery. Look up transitions and/or animations in css.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not show anythng

Comment: @Harry : ohh ok,,, i did not noticed that :D  . TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because the jQuery `fadeOut` function sets `display` of the element to `none` along with changing `opacity` to 0. Once the element's `display` becomes `none`, we are no longer hovering on the element even though the mouse is in the same position and so the hover out event kind of sets in, once this sets in and the fade-in is being done, the hover event again kicks in and it kind of goes into a cyclic loop.

One way to avoid the `fadeOut` affecting the `display` setting would be to manually set the `display` to `block` once the fade out is completed.

```js
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function() {
  return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).css('display', 'block'); // added this line
      $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').stop().fadeIn();
    });
  },

  function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function() {
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().fadeIn();
    });
  });
```

```css
.footer_5 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 420px;
}
#hello {
  font-family: 'KeplerStd-MediumDisp';
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer_5">
  <p id="hello"><span class="first">Please say hello.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Another way to overcome this problem would be to use `animate()` function to change the `opacity` of element alone on hover in/out instead of the `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` functions. This way the `display` setting of the element is never affected and so it doesn't go into a loop.

```js
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function() {
  return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    });
  },

  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 800, function() {
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
.footer_5 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 420px;
}
#hello {
  font-family: 'KeplerStd-MediumDisp';
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer_5">
  <p id="hello"><span class="first">Please say hello.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Or alternately, it seems like we an even use the `fadeTo` function (which takes the end `opacity` as a argument). This also does not seem to affect the `display` property of the element.

```js
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function() {
  return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
      $(this).css('display', 'block'); // added this line
      $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
  },

  function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(800, 0, function() {
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().fadeTo(800, 1);
    });
  });
```

```css
.footer_5 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 420px;
}
#hello {
  font-family: 'KeplerStd-MediumDisp';
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer_5">
  <p id="hello"><span class="first">Please say hello.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[Reference for the approach used in the 3rd snippet was this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549389/jquery-fadeout-without-display-none). The other two were identified by self through jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$(this).stop().fadeOut(500, function () {` from JQuery will give you desire output.

```
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {
        $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').stop().fadeIn();
},

function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94f84ngg/1/)**

Comment: But that would do away with the fade out of original text which I don't think is what OP needs.

Comment: @Harry As i think. I ask what they need. *I want the text to change but I don't want that blinking effect to happen*

Comment: *but I don't want that blinking effect to happen. I just want it to change at once.* - My interpretation was that the fade-out should happen once and only once but not blink like in the code in question. Anyway, let's leave it to OP to decide :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this without any effect. Just show and hide.

```
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim(); })
.hover(
    function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>').show(); 
    },

    function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).show()
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the fadeOut and FadeIn and it will work have a look below :

[here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94f84ngg/2/)

```
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).html('<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#222;" href="mailto:sfssfl.com">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</a>');

},

function () {

        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS MY SOLUTION (i have given red color to text ):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/94f84ngg/4/)

```
$('#hello').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {

        $(this).html('<a href="mailto:sfssfl.com"><font color="red">sfsfsfs@gmail.com</font></a>').stop().fadeIn();
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");

},

function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).stop().fadeIn();
    });
});
```