# jQuery show/hide doesn't keep free space for elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently I'm creating a website for a clothing company with use of HTML, CSS and JS. I wanted to create nice landing page with elements showing one by one like in presentation.

First of all I tried using jQuery functions .hide() at the beginning and .show() when I wanted to show it. They are working just fine and I really like the "slide" effect .show() function does. Only problem is these functions don't hold the space for the element which I need.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myelement").hide()
},0);

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myelement").show(500)
},500);
```

After that I tried doing this with changing style.visibility = "hidden" and = "visible" when I want it to show. These are also working great, and they keep the free space for my element. Problem is they don't have any showing effect, they just pop up like its nothing which doesn't look that nice.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('myelement').style.visibility = "visible";
},500);
```

So my question is, is there any way of combining these two or using better functions to keep the space for my hidden element but using some nice effect when showing?

I would still consider myself as a beginner and would really appreciate beginner-friendly answers.

Thank you!

Comment: [`fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)?

Comment: for effect u can use animated.css and if u want space u should use visibility

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, jQuery fadeOut() changes the display style property to none once visibility is 0.

Comment: Just toggle class and set animations via CSS.

Comment: fadeOut and fadeIN should work too, I will definitely try those, thank you. But I'm talking about the "slide from the side" effect .show() does.

Comment: @JoelHager I have to look up how to set animations via CSS, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: It's called '@keyframes' if you just want a fade in, set class opacity 0 and use a transition.

Comment: Or this? [jQuery fadeOut without display none?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4549389)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!